# ¿como refrescar un formulario que contiene tablas dinámicas con tiempo?

Tags: java, bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

Estoy usando un carousel de bootstrap para pasar las tablas (estas son generadas desde la db), trate de usar el poll de prime-faces pero este solo me recarga una vez y luego de eso la primera tabla se mantiene estática y pierde efecto de transición.
Alguna recomendacion...

psdta: Primefaces 4.0, y bootstrap 4 son parte del diseño.

```html
  <h:form id="tablas">
                    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
                    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" resizable="false" draggable="false" closable="false"
                              showHeader="false" style="border: none; opacity: 0.75;">
                    <p:graphicImage id="refreshTable" value="./../resources/images/cargandoLogin.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; " />
                </p:dialog>
                <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="limiter">
                            <div class="container-table100">
                                <h:outputText value="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.dateTable}" escape="false"/>
                                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.contTabla}">
                                    <div id="main-container"> 
                                        <div class="tituloN">NOTAS</div>
                                        <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-orientation: upright;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col" style="background-color: #0f7ff4">TEMAS PENDIENTES</th>
                                                        <th scope="col" style="background-color: #0f7ff4">NOTAS</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="text-align: left; border-left: 15px black !important;">
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.itemNotas.tareas}" escape="false"/> </td>
                                                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.itemNotas.notas}" escape="false"/></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="text-align: right;">Disponibilidad:</td>
                                                    <td><h:outputText value= "#{beansSeguimientoRelease.itemNotas.disponibilidad}" escape="false"/></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="text-align: right;">Operador Noc:</td>
                                                    <td><h:outputText value="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.itemNotas.operador_noc}" escape="false"/> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a id="aPrev" class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="width: 5%">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a id="aNext" class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next" style="width: 5%">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p:poll id="Tpoll" interval="#{beansSeguimientoRelease.cont}" update="tablas"/>
                </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar javascript, la funcion setInterval.
Esa función se ejecuta cada x segundos y puedes dentro de ella ejecutar un javascript que actualice el carrousel (u otra cosa).

Te paso un link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Espere te sirva!!

Comment: Bro tendría que añadir el id del formulario dentro de la función.

Algo así:
setInterval(function(){ #tablas; }, 3000);